# Irritating 'gramma' tag

Tags: discussion

It seems that someone has accidentally created a tag with the name 'gramma'. This comes up as the first option when you are trying to use the 'grammar' tag. Is there some way we can get rid of this tag?

Comment: I just edited the question's tag (https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/99820/understanding-verb%e3%81%aeverb-adjective). Since there are now no more questions with this tag, I believe the tag should disappear in 24 hours (can't find the post which describes this, though).

Comment: @dROOOze - [Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753) the canonical post :)